# Are there real-world Recipes for Middle Earth?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, food

I will be having a Lord of the Rings Risk party at my house on the seventh and was thinking about trying to have a few food items from the books.  I'm just wondering if any of you could recommend any **resources** online or otherwise that might help in my entertainment endeavors.

Comment: I know Tolkien was invited to a feast with the Dutch Editors, and they made *Maggot Soup* to honour farmer maggot :)

Comment: @MadTux which was probably just mushroom soup, given that Maggot was a mushroom grower :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should have a look at this list of recipes: http://lotrscrapbook.bookloaf.net/other/recipes.html

Comment: It's probably better just to make any old mushroom dish from your best recipe book and *call* it "Merry's Mushroom Munch"; generally, recipes "from the book" are terrible, but that site might be an exception of course.

Comment: @MadTux given that most of the meals mentioned are rations eaten by travelers in the wild, having to rely on what they can catch or scrounge, haute quisine has no real place :)

Answer (score 2):

Also found this on the official Hobbit site:  [Hobbit Recipes](http://apps.warnerbros.com/thehobbit/recipes/us/)