# Real-world recipes for A Song of Ice and Fire

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

I saw [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/27184/are-there-real-world-recipes-for-middle-earth), and it made me think about a similar question regarding the A Song of Ice and Fire universe. **Are there some resources** (online or otherwise) **that you can suggest regarding recipes for food items for the ASOIAF series?**

Comment: I would just recommend the book and blog listed in System Down's answer, but you should know that some ingredients can be hard or impossible to find and you need substitutes.  The book is pretty good about listing these.  Aurochs, for example, are extinct, but you can use beef or other red meats instead.  Grains of Paradise, as another example, are an uncommon herb in the US, but are similar to peppercorns.

Comment: @CodexArcanum - I wonder what you can substitute for jellied dog brains and unborn puppies...

Comment: @SystemDown: Curiously enough, today I got to the exact part in ASOS where the Astapori slaver tells the slave translator that he will feast Dany with jellied dog brains and a stew of unborn puppies. Reminded me instantly of your comment!

Comment: @JNat - Maybe I should put spoiler markers on it lol

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There used to be a blog specifically for this called Cooking Ice and Fire, but unfortunately it's down.

However, there is an official cook book called [Feast of Ice and Fire](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDMQFjAA&url=http://www.amazon.com/Feast-Ice-Fire-Official-Companion/dp/0345534492&ei=OPKzUKegNs3oiwLv-4HYBw&usg=AFQjCNFReJGZSCQCKfHHUaQslENf3lqWpg&sig2=n4F2rpp8fsUv0iclmuVfdw&cad=rja).

Comment: The book you mention is actually based on a blog: http://www.innatthecrossroads.com/ The recipes are a mix of items from the blog and stuff exclusive to the book.

Answer (score 4):

There are two really good recipe books, one of which is already listed here (*[A Feast of Ice and Fire](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0345534492)*). The other is *[The Unofficial Game of Thrones Cookbook](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1440538727)*. They're both works of art and I enjoy comparing the recipes in both books.

#### *A Feast of Ice and Fire*

This book is endorsed by George R. R. Martin and is the better book in my opinion due to its inclusion of pictures. *A Feast of Ice and Fire* also typically has two versions of each recipe, one that's more historically accurate and one "modern" recipe that is perhaps better suited to the typical Western palate.

#### *The Unofficial Game of Thrones Cookbook*

There have been some issues with *The Unofficial Game of Thrones Cookbook* with plagiarism — some people say that the recipes are copied from other unofficial cookbooks and slapped with a new GoT-inspired title.

---

For a diehard fan, you need both cookbooks, but if you're interested in just tasting a few recipes or getting a present for a GoT fan, the official Feast of Ice and Fire is the one to go with.